# "..." occurs when try to change label in Xcode/Swift

Tags: xcode

In Xcode, whenever I try to change the text in a label, it will always appear as "..." on my screen. Is this because the labels are being too confined into the stack views, and if so how can I fix this?

Comment: It's because they don't fit on the frame size of your current label. And your label doesn't have any constraints set. Try adding constraints like the position where the label should be, and it will resize automatically to fit its contents.

Comment: In `viewDidAppear` print the frame of the label. The text might be wider than what the label can accommodate. Can you paste the code for your stack view ?

Comment: with label.sizeToFit(), you can request a redrawing of the label. If you cannot modify its frame, you cna also set the truncation mode for a uilabel the following way: label.lineBreakMode = ... https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslinebreakmode